# Injected Youtube iFrame wont autoplay despite correct parameter and attribute

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

I have a bunch of Youtube iFrames outputting on a page. As loading all of these will a performance issue, I have a script that will inject the iFrame makrkup when a user clicks on an associated thumbnail image.

The problem is that in **Chromium browsers** despite having `&autoplay=1` param and the `allow="autoplay;"` attribute the video won't autoplay. (Slight correction here, I should say videos inconsistently autoplay - maybe 20% of the time.)

If I add `&mute=1` videos will play each time but this isn't acceptable.
If I copy and paste the markup directly to the page (i.e. the stuff generated after the script has run) it will play each time.

[**Example**](https://codepen.io/LMG/pen/zYqBZWa)

```
<div class="lazyloaded-video" data-youtube-video="tmQkY0QBGXA"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/77/560/315" class="lazyloaded-video__placeholder"></div>
```

```
function youtubeLazyLoad() {
    var lazyloadedVideo = $('.lazyloaded-video');
    
    // Check if the video class is present 
    if (lazyloadedVideo.length) {
        
        // On click we will remove the img and add the iframe along with with the full video URL. 
        $('.lazyloaded-video__placeholder').click(function (e) {
            var lazyLoadedVideoID = $(this).parent(lazyloadedVideo).data('youtube-video');
            $(this).parent(lazyloadedVideo).html(
                    '<iframe class="iframe" width="560" height="315" allow="autoplay;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + lazyLoadedVideoID + '?autoplay=1" ></iframe>'
            );
        });
    }
}
youtubeLazyLoad();
```

Comment: Have you tried autoplay the video with `mute=1` and after the first second, enable volume?. I've read some questions here on Stack overflow about autoplay and as far as I remember, this, cannot be done *(YouTube disabled autoplay with volume, hence, you have to use `mute=1`)*.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, thanks for the response. `mute=1` is a param so I'm not sure how I could get around that without forcing a reload. I did try to simulate a click after a timeout (`$('iframe').click();`) but that didn't work. As I said in the OP, if I paste the same iFrame markup that is generated by the script it will play with sound on page load each time. I've update the example to show this.